# Como actualizar tabla desde Gridview

Tags: asp.net, vb.net

Tengo el siguiente gridView con una columna de tipo CheckBox, lo que busco es cargar en el GridView los datos de una tabla,una vez cargados los datos, seleccionar con los CheckBox los campos que requieren cambiar de estado y una vez seleccionados los campos haga el UPDATE en la tabla desde un boton.

```
   <asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="False" >
        <Columns>
              <asp:TemplateField>
            <HeaderTemplate>
                <asp:CheckBox ID="chkHeader" runat="server" />
            </HeaderTemplate>
            <ItemTemplate>
                <asp:CheckBox ID="chkRow" runat="server" />
            </ItemTemplate>
        </asp:TemplateField>
             <asp:BoundField DataField="id" HeaderText="id"  />
            <asp:BoundField DataField="matricula" HeaderText="matricula"  />              
        </Columns>
    </asp:GridView>
```

Lo estoy tratando de hacer de la siguiente manera pero no lo consigo

```
  Protected Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs)
    For Each row As GridViewRow In GridView1.Rows
        If TryCast(row.FindControl("chkRow"), CheckBox).Checked Then
            Dim constr As String = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings("EJEMPLOConnectionString").ConnectionString
            Using con As New SqlConnection(constr)
               Using cmd As New SqlCommand("UPDATE matricula SET estado = activo where id=@id")
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@id",Convert.ToInt32(row.Cells[2].Text))
                con.Open()
                cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()

            End Using
            End Using
        End If
    Next
End Sub
```

Comment: hola.. que quiere decir, no lo consigo??? y a ese update le falta un where... por lo menos para identificar la fila

Comment: Hola.. me refiro a actualizar el campo en la base de datos

Comment: Y que error tira? Y probaste ese query en la dbm esta recibiendo bien el parametro id?